Drive Permissions and Filesystem Issues After Transferring Ubuntu to New Machine
I transferred my Ubuntu drive and secondary drives to a new machine, but now the drive permissions have defaulted to root, and I'm unable to change them back to my username.
I have 2 secondary drives they are lvm2 grouped together by logical volume group but the LVG now shows as NTFS partition.

Ubuntu files in a root filesystem should be on an ext4 filesystem.  Data files may be on anything, but expect to lose capabilities like owner and permissions.
